# NET USE Error 1219 even though there are no existing connections

Tags: mapping, network-drive, net-use

I'm trying to map a network drive of an SBS 2011 server.
Even though there are no existing connections (net use returns an empty list, process explorer doesn't find any handles for connections to the server) I get 1219 error message.

In order to map the drive I use the following commands:

1. NET USE * /D /YES
2. NET USE y: \\sbs\[dir_name] /USER:[domain_name]\[username] /PERSISTENT:YES

The environment:

- Windows SBS 2011 Server (\sbs)
- Win7 Professional 64Bit, in sbs domain

I can map the drive using the IP address, but the program needing to access the drive tries to access it via its name (\sbs) and fails (well, I think at least that this is the reason).

Another bit of info:

I previously had joined the domain with a different user (user1). For some reasons I left and rejoined the domain using a different one (user2).

When trying to map the drive in Windows Explorer it automatically suggests user1. Could it be that there are some old settings that make Windows think that user1 is still connected to sbs?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.